# Store data having a double quote in a javascript var

Tags: javascript

I have a var in script which has data like . But when i add this to another variable its not working.

```
var x = '32"';

onclick="javascript:selectSize(' + "'" + x + "'" + ');"
```

I want

```
onclick="javascript:selectSize('32"');"
```

But it becomes

```
onclick="javascript:selectSize('32"');""=""
```

i don't know whats happening

Comment: should this: `"javascript:selectSize(' + "'"`  not be `"javascript:selectSize(" + "'"`?

Comment: The code in the question does not replicate the problem described in the question. Add a [mcve] to the question actually demonstrating the problem, ideally a **runnable** one using Stack Snippets.

Comment: The best answer here, really, is: Don't use strings with `onclick`. Instead, use functions: `someElement.onclick = function() { selectSize(x); };` Separately: You don't use the `javascript:` pseudo-protocol in `onxyz` strings, just places where URLs are expected (`href`, etc.). It's harmless, but wrong.

Comment: This is just a typographical mistake. [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/7g83xxgu/)

Comment: i dont understnd know what u r saying... it takes whole string selectsize(---)

Answer (score -1):

from comment, Make use of encode/decode URI Component as follows

```js
var a=encodeURIComponent('abc"');
console.log(a);
console.log(decodeURIComponent(a));
```

Comment: it will work , but i am just showing you the code here. the value 32" will come from database. i cannot modify it.

Comment: ``\`` is not an escape character in HTML. That won't work.

Comment: but in JavaScript, it is. And OP says about JavaScript variable

Comment: @SagarV — But the problem is that the JavaScript is being used to generate HTML and the problem occurs once that HTML (generated from JS) is parsed by the HTML parser.

Answer (score -1):

```
onclick="javascript:selectSize('32"');"
        ^                         ^
```

The HTML parser will parse the attribute value before passing the value of it to the JS engine for execution.

You are using a `"` to delimit the attribute value.

The second `"` ends the attribute value.

If you want to use `"` as data in an attribute value delimited with `"` then you must express it as an entity (e.g. `&quot;`).

```
var html_x = x.replace(/"/g, "&quot;");
```

---

Escaping becomes very painful when you start generating nested languages.

You have JavaScript embedded in HTML embedded in JavaScript.

Avoid mashing strings together to construct your DOM. Use DOM methods directly instead.

```
var x = '32"';
var button = document.createElement("button");
button.addEventListener("click", function (event) { 
    selectSize(x);
});
```

Comment: OP mentioned that it is from Database and can't change

Comment: @SagarV — I never suggested changing the data in the database. It can be modified after it gets to the browser.

Comment: so after it comes to client can i add a \ symbol before the "

Comment: @askandanswer — Not to solve your problem. ``\`` is not an escape character for HTML, and your problem is how the `"` is treated by the HTML parser.